# How to create Caesar code with multi-digit key?

Tags: c++, caesar-cipher

So I need to create a code that reads a string of digits (the key) and reads a string of characters. Instead of the usual caesar code, each number in the key is assigned to the corresponding letter in the string. For example: Key: 2563 and Characters: abcdefg, the code would be as follows 2-a 5-b 6-c 3-d 2-e 5-f 6-g. This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char loop, k,ch;
string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string key="";
string original, result="";
do{
    cout<<"String to encode: ";
    cin>>loop;
    cout<<"Input a string of digits: ";
    cin>>key;
    cout<<"Input a string to encode: ";
    cin>>original;
    int i=0;
    do{
        for(int j=0;j<key.length();j++){
            k=key[j];
            result=result+(char)('a' + (int)(((original[i] - 'a') + k) % 
 26));
            i++;
        }
    }while(i<original.length());
    cout<<result<<endl;
    
    
}while(loop!='N');
return 0;
}
```

But I am not getting the right code output, I keep getting random letters that are not applicable to the code. Can anyone supply any help on how the caesar code works with multidigit keys? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: `key[j]` returns the character in the string (an ASCII code), not the digit value.

Comment: Here's an explanation for caesar's cypher https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/